# Overwriting bound methods in python when function requires class attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Say I have a class:

```
class Data():
    def __init__(self):
        self.scores = [] 
        self.encoding= {1: 'first', 2: 'second', 3:'third'}
    def build():
        self.scores = [1, 2, 3]
    def translate(self):
        return [self.encoding[score] for val in self.scores]
```

Now I want to be able to translate the columns for a given data object...

```
# I want to be able to do
d= Data()    
d.scores.translate()
# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'translate'

# Instead of
d= Data()    
d.translate()
```

Now I am fully aware that I am trying to access a method that does NOT exist for that list (translate()). I want to be able to make method calls as is mentioned above (d.scores.translate()) because I may have some specific subslice of d.scores I want to translate.

For Example, if d.scores was a nested numpy array (I only want to translate 1st 5 columns but keep all rows)

```
#this is what I would like to be able to do
d.scores[:, 1:5].translate()

# And I don't want to build a kwarg in the translate method to handle it like
d.scores.translate(indices=[1])
```

I know this is more of an implementation question, and I'm wondering what the best practice should be.

Am I trying to force a square peg into a round hole at this point? Should I just give up and define a module function or consider the kwargs? Is that more 'pythonic'?

**UPDATE**

**I should have said this sooner but I did try using the kwarg and staticmethod route. I just want to know if there are other ways to accomplish this? Maybe through subclassing? or Python's equivalent of interfacing in java/C# (if it exists?)**

Comment: also brownie points for whoever figures out what this problem is called? Or how it is referenced in other languages? I found it difficult to find a way to ask this question in one line without providing examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are trying to "force a square peg into a round hole".

Your translate method works on the whole scores list, full stop. This can not be changed with some trickery, which is simply not supported in Python.

When you want to do subslices, I would recommend doing it explicitly.

Examples:

```
# Using args/kwargs:
scores = john.translate(10, 15) # translate subslice 10:15

# Using a new static method:
scores = Person.translate_scores(john.scores[10:15])
```

Looks not that elegant, but works.

(BTW: Since you changed your question, my classes might be a little of, but I will not change my answer with every edit you make)

Your trickery simply does not work, because "scores" is not some part of your main class, but simply an attribute of it, which has its own type. So, when you do "d.scores.translate()" translate is not called on d, but on a list or whatever type scores is. You can not change that, because it is core Python.

Comment: wow you responded before I could even finish editing :) 
Thanks for the tip. I figured as much and actually had both the kwarg and static method built. Just wanted to open up the discussion on other ways around this

Comment: @codebrotherone: Ok, there might be more methods to do what you want, but I explained why your preferred syntax can not work. I add another answer with a different solution.

Comment: Sorry about that I keep forgetting editing posts can get touchy here on SO. I'll keep it static from here on out, I think I said what I need to say

Comment: @codebrotherone: Have a look on my second answer. This will circumvent the inherited limitations of Python by using a different object for Data.scores.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by using a second class and use _scores for the list and a sub-object scores which manipulates _scores:

```
class DataHelper(object):
   def __init__(self, data_obj):
       self.data_obj = data_obj

   def translate(self, *args):
       ... # work on self.data_obj._scores

class Data(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.scores = DataHelper(self)
       self._scores = []
```

With such a class structure, you might be able to to this:

```
scores = d.scores.translate(1, 5)
```

And with more trickery, you might be able to even do:

```
scores = d.scores[1:5].translate()
```

But for that, you will need a third class (objects of that will be created temporary on indexing scores objects, so that d.scores[1:5] will not create a list slice but a new object with translate method).